# How can I have consistent-return with exhaustive switch-case statements?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have code like this:

```
function (flavors: IceCreamFlavor): 'like'|'dislike' {
    switch (flavors) {
        case IceCreamFlavor.vanilla:
            return 'dislike';
        case IceCreamFlavor.chocolate:
            return 'like';
    }
}
```

This is exhaustive, and I have an eslint rule that ensures exhaustiveness.

For eslint / typescript, i have the `consistent-return` rule switched to on, which will complain during this. I *don't* want to add a default (b/c if I add a new ice cream flavor, i want the developer to have to handle it), but consistent-return doesn't realize this is exhaustive and will complain.

Any ideas on how I can handle this elegantly?

Answer (score 12):

Okay, I figured out the problem with my question.

`consistent-return` comes from eslint, which doesn't know about types, so there's no great way of "fixing" consistent-return to know about this.

Probably the better way of doing it is to disable `consistent-return` and then to use [typescript-lint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint)'s `explicit-function-return-type` or even `no-unsafe-return` or something like that.

Because that would be really costly to move the whole codebase over to strongly typed functions, you could contribute a tslint rule that does `consistent-return` that *does* know about types, but if you're using ts, you probably just want to remove `consistent-return.`

Answer (score 4):

Probably way too late to help OP, but for any future readers:
the TS config option `noImplicitReturns` gives all the benefits of ESLint's `consistent-returns`, while also supporting exhaustive switches/etc. because it's type-aware.

for reference:

- https://blog.logrocket.com/exploring-advanced-compiler-options-typescript/#noimplicitreturns
- https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitReturns

Comment: This is the real answer!

Comment: So the correct answer is to disable the es-lint rule `"consistent-return": 0` and activate `"noImplicitReturns": true` inside `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 3):

You could siginify exhaustiveness by adding `never` return.

```
function (flavors: IceCreamFlavor): 'like'|'dislike' {
    switch (flavors) {
        case IceCreamFlavor.vanilla:
            return 'dislike';
        case IceCreamFlavor.chocolate:
            return 'like';
    }

    const _exhaustiveCheck: never = flavors;
    return _exhaustiveCheck;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think this *could* work, but is there something more elegant with eslint settings? This seems to add a lot of overhead.

Comment: It's not overhead, it's exhaustive! ;-)

Comment: I often use this trick for void-returning functions, so that there is a compile-time check for exhaustiveness in case I ever end up changing the enum or union type involved. With no return statement, a simple `let _check: never = ...;` at the end of the function is dead code and can be eliminated by a minifier, even if the minifier doesn't know the switch is exhaustive. If the function isn't void then Typescript should complain that not every branch returns the correct type, so at least when using strict mode (or the equivalent individual setting), this trick covers the one remaining case.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent some time figuring out a solution but it might be overkill. I refactored my switch statement to use a map instead:

```
type ButtonSize = 'large' | 'medium' | 'small';

// BEFORE (w/ switch statement)
function getSizeStyles(size: ButtonSize) {
  switch (size) {
    case 'large':
      return 'justify-start text-xl px-6 py-4 min-w-[320px]';
    case 'medium':
      return 'justify-center text-lg px-4 py-2 min-w-[150px]';
    case 'small':
      return 'justify-center text-sm px-2 py-1';
  }
}

// REFACTOR (uses a new "StyleMap")
type StyleMap<T extends string> = {
  [K in T]: string;
};

function getSizeStyles(size: ButtonSize) {
  const styles: StyleMap<ButtonSize> = {
    large: 'justify-start text-xl px-6 py-4 min-w-[320px]',
    medium: 'justify-center text-lg px-4 py-2 min-w-[150px]',
    small: 'justify-center text-sm px-2 py-1',
  };

  return styles[size];
}
```

Comment: I know this means that ultimately, I'm not using a switch statement, but I figured it was still sharing what I ended up to doing.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest another way:

```
function (flavors: IceCreamFlavor): 'like'|'dislike' {
    let flavor: string = '';
    
    switch (flavors) {
      case IceCreamFlavor.vanilla:
        flavor = 'dislike';
        break;
      case IceCreamFlavor.chocolate:
        flavor = 'like';
        break;
    }

    return flavor;
}
```